# Invalid address or ENS name

Tags: ethereum, metamask, nft, ethers.js, hardhat

I can't understand what the problem is. When I am run the app I am getting this error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: invalid address or ENS name (argument="name", value=5.050201689117535e+47, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.5.0)
```

My code is given below:

```
import {ethers} from 'ethers'
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Web3Modal from 'web3modal'

import { nftaddress, nftmarketaddress } from '../config'

import NFT from '../artifacts/contracts/NFT.sol/NFT.json'
import Market from '../artifacts/contracts/Market.sol/Market.json'

export default function Home() {
  const [nfts, setNFts] = useState([])
  const [loadingState, setLoadingState] = useState('not-loaded')

  useEffect(()=> {
    loadNFTs()
  }, [])

  async function loadNFTs() {
    // what we want to load:
    // ***provider, tokenContract, marketContract, data for our marketItems***

    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider()
    const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(nftaddress, NFT.abi, provider)
    const marketContract = new ethers.Contract(nftmarketaddress, Market.abi, provider)
    const data = await marketContract.fetchMarketTokens()

    const items = await Promise.all(data.map(async i => {
      const tokenUri = await tokenContract.tokenURI(i.tokenId)
      // we want get the token metadata - json 
      const meta = await axios.get(tokenUri)
      let price = ethers.utils.formatUnits(i.price.toString(), 'ether')
      let item = {
        price,
        tokenId: i.tokenId.toNumber(),
        seller: i.seller,
        owner: i.owner,
        image: meta.data.image, 
        name: meta.data.name,
        description: meta.data.description
      }
      return item
    }))

    setNFts(items)
    setLoadingState('loaded')
  }

  // function to buy nfts for market 

  async function buyNFT(nft) {
    const web3Modal = new Web3Modal()
    // const web3Modal = new Web3Modal({
    //   network: "ropsten", // optional
    //   cacheProvider: true, // optional
    //   providerOptions // required
    // });
    const connection = await web3Modal.connect()
    const provider = new ` `ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection)
    const signer = await provider.getSigner()
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(nftmarketaddress, Market.abi, signer)

    const price = ethers.utils.parseUnits(nft.price.toString(), 'ether')
    const transaction = await contract.createMarketSale(nftaddress, nft.tokenId, {
      value: price
    })

    await transaction.wait()
    loadNFTs()
  }
  if(loadingState === 'loaded' && !nfts.length) return (<h1
  className='px-20 py-7 text-4x1'>No NFts in marketplace</h1>)

  return (
    <div className='flex justify-center'>
          <div className='px-4' style={{maxWidth: '1600px'}}>
          <div className='grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-4 pt-4'>
            {
              nfts.map((nft, i)=>(
                <div key={i} className='border shadow rounded-x1 overflow-hidden'>
                  <img src={nft.image} />
                  <div className='p-4'>
                    <p style={{height:'64px'}} className='text-3x1 font-semibold'>{
                      nft.name}</p>
                      <div style={{height:'72px', overflow:'hidden'}}>
                        <p className='text-gray-400'>{nft.description}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='p-4 bg-black'>
                        <p className='text-3x-1 mb-4 font-bold text-white'>{nft.price} ETH</p>
                        <button className='w-full bg-purple-500 text-white font-bold py-3 px-12 rounded'
                        onClick={()=> buyNFT(nft)} >Buy
                        </button>
                      </div>
                </div>
              ))
            }
          </div>
          </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: the error explicitly tells you that the value is not an address and shows what exactly you pass to it which is `value=5.050201689117535e+47`

Answer (score 12):

I had exactly the same error message. The problem is your value for nftmarketaddress is most likely invalid.

**This is what it should look like:**

`export const nftmarketaddress = "0xcd3b766ccdd6ae721141f452c550ca635964ce71"`

Exported as a string.

**In my case I had an empty space after the opening quotation mark.**

`export const nftmarketaddress = " 0xcd3b766ccdd6ae721141f452c550ca635964ce71"`

The error means the address you are passing is not in the right format hence presenting as an INVALID_ARGUMENT. It needs to be in the format 0xcd3b766ccdd6ae721141f452c550ca635964ce71(42 hexadecimal characters) and as mentioned above exported as a string.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error while passing in the addresses as parameters to the contract. What solved the problem was:

```
const [deployer, acc1, acc2] = await ethers.getSigners();
```

and then at the contract constructor, I called:

```
acc1.address, acc2.address
```

Instead of:

```
acc1,acc2
```

So make sure you've got the `.address` at the end of each account.

Answer (score 0):

I run into  this error while trying to deploy using hardhat. Here is the fix

```
  const charityWallet = signers[1]
  const marketingWallet =signers[2]

  
  //We Deploy
  const givers = await Givers.deploy(charityWallet.address,marketingWallet.address,process.env.ROUTER02);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a mistake while passing the contract address I passed it as a number and that was the issue. ( do **NOT** do this )

**This is the correct way**

```
const contract = await ethers.getContractAt("Token","ADDRESS_OF_WALLET")
```

Now you can invoke the functions like this

```
await contract.name()
```

Answer (score 0):

From reading the other answers and resolving this issue when I encountered it, it seems to me that this error means you are passing a value which is not formatted as an Ethereum address into a function which expects an Ethereum address, i.e.

- What you are passing is not an address but a different object (in my case a "Signer" object which contained an address and its private key as members) or
- Your address is formatted incorrectly (for example, with extra whitespace or as a number).

Answer (score 0):

I get this error by passing an undefined element to a estimateGas Contract function when an address was expected. So if anybody else has this error, check the functions params too.