# How do I pass arguments to a mint function for the ERC155 smart contract?

Tags: reactjs, solidity, ethers.js, erc1155

I am trying to write a `handleMint()` function in my React app using Ethers.js. My smart contract uses the ERC1155 standard. I'm having trouble writing the `handleMint()` function so that it passes the necessary arguments to my smart contract's `mint` function. Here is my `handleMint()` function is `js`:

```js
async function handleMint1() {
    console.log(props.accounts)
    if (window.ethereum) {
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
      const signer = provider.getSigner();
      const contract = new ethers.Contract(
        charlesWhitsteenProjectAddress,
        charlesWhitsteenProjectNFT.abi,
        signer
      );
      try {
        const response = await contract.mint(props.accounts, BigNumber.from('1'), BigNumber.from(mintAmount1), {
          value: ethers.utils.parseEther((0.01 * mintAmount1).toString())
        });
        console.log('response: ', response);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('error: ', err)
      }
    }
  }
```

`props.accounts` is passing in the address of the connected wallet. `BigNumber.from('1')` is supposed to be the token ID, and the `BigNumber.from(mintAmount1`) is supposed to be the amount of tokens to mint.

Here is my `mint` function in Solidity:

```
function mint(address _recipient, uint256 _tokenId, uint256 _amount) public payable {

        if(whitelistedAddresses[msg.sender] == 0) {
            require(mintEnabled, "Minting has not been enabled.");
            require(msg.value == _amount * mintPrice, "Incorrect mint value.");
        } else {
            require(whitelistGiveaway, "Whitelist giveaway has not been enabled");
            require(isValid(_tokenId) == true, "Whitelist giveaway is no longer valid.");
            whitelistedAddresses[msg.sender] -= _amount;
        }

        require(_amount >= 1, "please enter a valid number");
        require(totalSupply[_tokenId] + _amount <= maxSupply, "Sorry, you have exceeded the supply.");
        require(tokenIdMints[msg.sender][_tokenId] + _amount <= maxPerTokenId, "Sorry, you have exceeded the alotted amount per token ID.");

        totalSupply[_tokenId] += _amount;
        tokenIdMints[msg.sender][_tokenId] += _amount;
        _mint(_recipient, _tokenId, _amount, "");
        
    }
```

And finally, here is the error message I'm getting in my console when I click the Mint button in my app:

```
error:  Error: invalid address or ENS name (argument="name", value=["0x.."], code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.6.2)
```

It looks like the problem, at this point is the address (`props.accounts`). Can anyone tell me how I can properly pass arguments to my `mint` function?

Comment: this may help...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70481285/invalid-address-or-ens-name

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the problem was that I needed to convert the address to a string.